# Review, answers and deleted questions

Tags: discussion, answers

I kind of got myself confused with this review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/5542779:

[image]

I thought the question was something to be desired, but I thought the answer was OK given the question. And since it was the only answer to the question, it was the only answer or advice future visitors would find.

However, the confusing part (for me) was the answer was provided for a deleted question. I looked at it for some time because I was kind of perplexed by it. It crossed my wires because I was trying to evaluate the answer on its own merits, and the deleted question made no sense.

I think its important to evaluate the answer separately from the question. I've seen some really great answers provided for some really poor questions. And if we evaluate a an answer with respect to the standing of a question, we may unfairly punish the person providing an answer.

**Question**: Should answers to deleted questions be evaluated on their own merits? Or should they be banished with the question they are associated with?

Comment: You link to the review, yet you blur the user's name and avi?  Also, his name is friggen right there in your imaeg:  Hoijof.  I don't understand this.  I don't think you understand it either.  Does anybody understand?  I feel like I'm falling...

Comment: @Will - I'm not sure what you are getting at. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaa.... faaaaaaaling....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's one of those weird edge cases. So someone flagged that answer as "very low quality" (a flag I would have declined). Unfortunately, the asker then deleted their question, taking the answer along with it. When that happened the flag was validated and the answer became an audit case.

I really don't think flagged posts like this deleted by the asker or answerer, and not a moderator, should be used as audit cases. This isn't the first time this has caused a problem, and it's why moderators are cautious about accepting these flags when we see them. The system either shouldn't auto-validate them or shouldn't use flags validated in this manner to set up audits.

Comment: Thanks Brad. So I'm clear: keep evaluating answers on their own merits? (I'm OK with an occasional fail. It happens).

Comment: @jww - Yeah, not much to be done with something like this until we have [a means of disputing individual audits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/188790#188790). I can't even invalidate the flag to remove this as an audit case, so it's going to stick around as a bad audit. I've had other problems with dismissed-on-deletion flags before: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175420/dont-automatically-dismiss-spam-offensive-flags-when-a-post-is-deleted-by-the